# nhibernate map property from list and query over

Tags: nhibernate, model, mapping, properties, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following situation in my objects

```
   public virtual Item CurrentItem 
    {
        get 
        {
            return (from n in Items
                    where n.IsCorrente
                    select n).FirstOrDefault();
        }             
    }

 private IList<Item > _Items;
        public virtual IList<Item> Items
        {
            get { return _Items; }
        }
```

when i try to query the currentItem property i have the "could not resolve property" exception
what is the best solution?
I need to map the rule "where n.Iscorrente" in the hbm map file? having a simple get {} property ???

or i have to change the query mode to include the collection ??

I am using Nhibernate 3.1, this is a semplicistic sample, but the problem is a real problem.

The Item object in real app is a complex object and the Items collection is the storical situation of data.

I have put the private collection becouse of i use automapper and i have to map

```
<bag name="Items" cascade="save-update" access="field.camelcase-underscore"
```

What is the best solution to have a property rapresenting a single object from a nested collection?

Something like Person->jobs->currentjob and so on

TIA
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read CurrentItem and don't want to persist it then you can use a formula for your property.

```
<property name="CurrentItem" type="Example.Item, Example" formula="(SELECT * FROM Items WHERE IsCorrente = 'y')" />
```

The only catch with this approach is you'll have to have Item implement the IUserType interface.

Comment: Obviously that type of select is implemented to retrieve Items collections (eg. select x,y,z from ITEMS where ITEMS.IDPArent=parent.id).   If i implement IUserInterface i need to change my poco strategy, btw can i query against Item property with linq not having could not resolve property???

Comment: Item is a class already mapped with his properties hbm file, how i can implement with a IuserType ??

Comment: Your example class already violates the "Plain" strategy since you have the tie to the NHibernate LINQ provider in the get.  Using the mapping file to fill this property would align with POCO slightly more.  I don't have an implementation of IUserType handy but there is the start of one at the bottom of this post: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Entities-dependencies-best-practices.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here where you dont map CurrentItem at all and use

1:

```
    public virtual Item CurrentItem
    {
        get { return Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.IsCurrente); }
    }
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; private set; }
```

2:
a little workaround

```
    public virtual Item CurrentItem
    {
        get { return Items.FirstOrDefault(); }
    }
    protected virtual IList<Item> CurrentItems { get; private set; }
```

Hope that helps